# Project reactor Netty

Tags: java, spring, blockchain, netty, project-reactor

I am working on a java blockchain project and I have a question regarding inbound and outbound connections.

I have this server setup:

```
@Bean
    public Mono<Void> startServer() throws RocksDBException {
        return TcpServer.create()
                .doOnConnection(c -> log.info("Peer connected!"))
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
                .handle(transmissionHandler())
                .port(7331)
                .doOnBound(server -> log.info("Server started on address:{} and port:{}", server.address(), server.port()))
                .doOnUnbound(server -> log.info("Server stopped!"))
                .bindNow()
                .onDispose();
    }

@Bean
    public TransmissionHandler transmissionHandler() {
        return new TransmissionHandler();
    }
```

And for TransmissionHandler method

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TransmissionHandler implements BiFunction<NettyInbound, NettyOutbound, Flux<Void>> {
    @Autowired
    private Processor messageProcessor;
    private NettyOutbound outbound;

    private NettyInbound inbound;

    @Override
    public Flux<Void> apply(NettyInbound inbound, NettyOutbound outbound) {
        this.outbound = outbound;
        this.inbound = inbound;

        return Flux.never();
    }

    public NettyInbound getInbound() {
        return inbound;
    }

    public NettyOutbound getOutbound() {
        return outbound;
    }
}
```

If multiple clients(A,B,C) connects to the server, A send a message and wait a response, B send a message to server, if the server receives a message with instruction 'broadcastAll' it means that ti should broadcast that message to all connected clients.

My question is in the `.handle(transmissionHandler())` will handle each connection one by one, so for example one client will send a message the server will 'talk' with that client only?

As a potential solution I am thinking to create a new @Bean that will take care of the all connection clients, if the server receives a message with instruction 'broadcastAll' then loop to each connection and send a message to each connected client.

It is a bit hard to try tcp connection on a single machine, I am thinking of deploying them on a kubernetes env and a pod = a machine.

Comment: if you want to  `broadcastAll` at server side  , it is necessary that build a context  store  all client connections，

Comment: So I could store all new connection in a list and when I want to broadcast to all, I can simply loop that list and call ```connection.outbound().send()``` with the specific message?

Comment: When asking a question, please use a title that summarizes your actual question. A title like _"Project reactor Netty"_ is not a good question title.

Comment: yes , correctly , just store every connection and loop  when it is needed

Comment: You usually don't loop through connections. It's easier and more Reactive-friendly to merge multiple Publishers, one of which could be a Sink used to broadcast. Btw, how do you close/handle the connection since you return `Flux.never()`?

Comment: I dont need to close the connection, since I need to keep it persistent, like in a peer to peer, so I need to always listen process the request and respond either to one or all clients.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's better to use Reactor components here instead of manual loping through connections. For broadcasting it provides `Sinks` with multicast capability.

Create a shared variable (could be withing a separate bean):

```
val sink = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer()
```

Then when you want to broadcast from any connection you just:

```
sink.emitNext(msg) { s, r ->
    // process error
}
```

(take a look at javadoc https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/index.html?reactor/core/publisher/FluxSink.html how to handle NON_SERIALIZABLE which you'll probably have)

And then you connect this sink output to other fluxes to make your outbound. I'm not sure how you can make it with your current bean which just returns a never completing flux, but assume that's just a temp draft and then the real code would be something like:

```
public Flux<Void> apply(NettyInbound inbound, NettyOutbound outbound) {
    Flux responses = inbound.flatMap { 
        // your main logic, response to incoming requests, produce new, etc.
    };
    // you would probably want a takeUntil / takeWhile to make sure it doesn't keep half-closed connections, though I guess Netty takes care of it too
    Flux broadcast = sink.asFlux();

    outbound.send(Flux.merge(responses, broadcast))
                .then();
}
```